# SPARQL statement not returning proper results

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl

I'm running a SPARQL statement but it is not returning the proper results. I'm using TopBraid Composer against [my OWL file (in RDF/XML)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/index.owl). First of all, the following SPARQL gives me the result `rdf:type`:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wo:<http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * where {
    <http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Animal#kingdom> ?type wo:Kingdom
}
```

When I run this query, I expect to get `<http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Animal#kingdom>`, but I get an empty result set:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wo:<http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * where {
    ?x rdf:type wo:Kingdom
}
```

What am I getting an empty result set?

Comment: Much the same question -- http://answers2.semanticweb.com/questions/25255/sparql-not-returning-the-proper-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not accurate to say that:

> First of all, the [first] SPARQL gives me the result `rdf:type`

You should be (and I expect that you are) getting

```
http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type
```

for that result.  However, since you've defined the `rdf:` prefix in an unusual way, `rdf:type` (according to your prefix definition) would be:

```
http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#type
```

Those are clearly different IRIs.  The problem is that you've made `rdf:` and `rdfs:` the same:

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
```

Assuming you wanted the standard definitions, these should be:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
```